# Is there a way to store right angle triangle made of int ellements in a 2 dimentional array?

Tags: java, arrays

The problem comes when I have to give a specific number of elements in the column section [rows][column] because column is always changing acording to the line. The number of colums are dependent on the line.For example in in the first row one column is needed and in the second row 2 columns are needed. I have got: int[][] Triangle = new int [lines][?].

Comment: How about an array of ArrayLists. Each "row" is an ArrayList, and could grow as needed independently of the other rows.

Comment: What issues do you have with 2d array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's syntactically valid to not give a number for the second dimension at initialization. This is a good reason; where the length of each sub array is a different value. Be careful you don't go out of bounds when you're accessing it later though.

For example, here's a right triangle angle matrix as a 10x10 right triangle:

```
int[][] triangle = new int[10][];
for(int i = 0; i < triangle.length; i++){
    triangle[i] = new int[i+1];
    for(int j = 0; j < triangle[i].length; j++){
        triangle[i][j] = j;
    }
}
```

If you know you're going to want a right triangle (or any other 2d polygon I suppose) of definite shape, you certainly want to use a 2d matrix over nested arraylists or other collections.

Comment: Note that I did i+1 for the first array so the ith array (0 based) has length i+1. Depending on how you're using the 0 row index in your triangle you may want to change that to just i.